# Unit Test class that uses only local variables for composition

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mocking

I am writing app that uses various REST api endpoints with very similar properties. Only difference is in endpoint adress and payload. Headers, method and other stuff remain the same. That is why I created class to communicate with my remote host, it is called `RestApiCommunicator` that has method `generateRequestAndCallEndpoint(List payload)` that wraps payload with all required stuff needed to perform rest call.
Than, I have various classes that only call this communicator class with proper endpoint suffix an its resources.
Everything is working fine but I want to unit test all of those classes. I was trying to figure out how to do that by reading a lot of SO questions but they are rather complicated cases, my is very simple.
I am trying to figure out a proper way to unit test a class that looks like this one:

```
class MyRestClient {

    public void useRestApi(List<MyResources> myResources) {
        RestApiCommunicator restApiCommunicator = new RestApiCommunicator ("/some/endpoint");
        restApiCommunicator.generateRequestAndCallEndpoint(myResources);
    }
}
```

I want to test if communicator was created with proper enpoint adress and if `generateRequestAndCallEndpoint` was called exacly once with my sample payload.

Only thing that comes to my mind is that make `restApiCommunicator` a field, create setter for this field and mock it in Unit tests. But this seems to me as rather dirty solution and I wouldn't like to modify my code to allow tests.

Maybe you can point me in some direction where I could have this class tested using some good pattern.

(ps. If that matters - this is a Spring Boot app)

Answer (score 0):

You could provide a factory for the communicator

```
class MyRestClient {
    private RestApiCommunicatorFactory factory = ...

    public void useRestApi(List<MyResources> myResources) {
        factory.getCommunicator("/some/endpoint")
            .generateRequestAndCallEndpoint(myResources);
    }
```

In your unit test, you provide a mock of the factory, which returns mock communicators. The specific language for that depends on your mocking library of choice.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do exactly what you ask (ie, "to test if communicator was created with proper enpoint adress and if `generateRequestAndCallEndpoint` was called exactly once with my sample payload") is to mock it using JMockit:

```
public final class MyRestClientTest {
    @Tested MyRestClient restClient;
    @Mocked RestApiCommunicator restApi;

    @Test
    public void verifyUseOfRestApi() {
        List<MyResource> resources = asList(new MyResource("a"), new MyResource("b"));

        restClient.useRestApi(resources);

        new Verifications() {{
            new RestApiCommunicator("/some/endpoint");
            restApi.generateRequestAndCallEndpoint(resources); times = 1;
        }};
    }
}
```